# Tabs menu with ionic framework

Tags: mobile, tabs, responsive-design, ionic-framework

i use ionic-framework to create my webapp. I need to insert in the middle of the page (inside ion-content) a block with 3 tabs. There is a conponent called ion-tabs but it has only 2 possibilities of position: bottom or top. Nobody knows any solutions? thanx

```
<ion-view>

    <!-- TOP BAR -->
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left"></ion-nav-buttons>

    <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
    <ion-content class="has-header">      
    ...some content
    TABS menu
    ...other content
    </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```